# How to move opengl objects without changing persective of the system?

Tags: opengl

I have the below output in opengl. [image]
But the object loads a bit below the window. I want to render it a bit up in the window without changing how it looks. The expected output i want is this
[image]. I hope I have clarified my requirements enough.

My inital camera position is:

```
pos = {5,0,2};
l = {-1,0,0};
r = {0,1,0};
u = {0,0,1};
gluLookAt(pos.x,pos.y,pos.z,
              pos.x+l.x,pos.y+l.y,pos.z+l.z,
              u.x,u.y,u.z);
// draw
glRotatef(angleRotationZ, 0,0 , 1);
```

The octahedron is drawn as one triangle with coordinate at `(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)` and other triangles are the rotated versions of this.

I tried changing the x,y,z coordiantes, and also camera positions. But those changes the perspective like the one shown.

Comment: Code showing how you manage the coords and matrix transformations would help a lot.

Comment: @Ripi2 I have added my inital camera position and orientation. I hope this makes it a bit clear?

Comment: Sorry, not enough. Post object coords too.

Comment: The octahedron is drawn as one triangle with coordinate at (1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1) and other triangles are the rotated versions of this.

Comment: Try with a small increment of tetrahedron's coords (1.01,0, 0, etc). Don't touch other coords (grid, camera)

Answer (score 1):

Your description matches what a tilt-shift lens would do; i.e. you're interested in shifting the image without changing the projected image. This can be achieved by passing asymmetrical left/right or top/bottom planes to `glFrustum`, or simply translating the projection matrix after it was initialized by any other method:

```
float cx = ..., cy = ...; // the point to center in the viewpoint
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
gluPerspective(...); // or whatever
glTranslatef(-cx, -cy, 0);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
// render scene
```

To calculate `cx` and `cy`, however, you may need to project the point of interest (e.g. the scene origin) to the image plane without the translation, and then translate by that amount. You can use `glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, ...)` and `glGetFloatv(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, ...)` to retrieve the matrices mid-calculation; however you may have better luck if you use a proper matrix-handling library instead of the legacy OpenGL functions for that.